# Triggering a function using `ng-click` inside a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have an app where users can submit posts for review, when they click on the add post button I use a bootstrap to confirm their choice. The bootstrap modal contains a "confirm" button which actually triggers a function.

For some reason that button does not work when placed inside the modal. It works if placed outside the whole modal, anywhere within the body tag.

Below is the code:

```
<button type="submit" id="createPostBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmModal">CONFIRM & SEND POST</button>

 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addPost('<%= uid %>')">Confirm</button>
  </div>
```

What am I missing here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where you added your form ? inside the modal or outside ?

Comment: @BimalDas the form is outside the modal.

Comment: you mean to say ng-click = addPost() not triggering the function which you are expecting ?

Comment: update your question with how you are opening modal, can I see your controller's code ?

Comment: @BimalDas yes, `ng-click` does nothing. But only within the modal. outside the same function works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use bootstrap modal in your angularJS project, you have to use "UI Bootstrap's" directives. visit [this](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)